# Verificar se existe número repetido e eliminalos

Tags: c, array

Entrar com os dados em VET, e depois verificar os números repetidos, e deixar no VET1 só os números que não estão repetidos, mas não to conseguindo fazer essa última parte de jeito nenhum, segue o código que fiz até agora:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define T 3

int main()
{
    int vet[T];
    int vet1[T];
    int i, j, achou = 0, quant = 0;

    printf("Digitar os numeros:");
    for(i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {

        for(j = 0; j < quant; j++)
        {
            achou = 0;
            if(vet[i] == vet1[j])
            {
                achou = 1;
                break;
            }
            if(achou == 0)
            {
                vet1[quant] = vet[i];
                quant ++;
            }
        }

    }
    for (i = 0; i <= quant; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", vet[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: o segundo laço nunca sera executado pq quant é zero

Comment: mesmo muudando para T, ainda assim nao funciona :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consegui fazer:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define T 5

int main(){
int vet[T];
int vet1[T];
int i, j, n= 0;

printf("Digitar os numeros:");
for(i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        for( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if( vet[i] == vet1[j] )
                break;
        }

        if( j == n )
        {
            vet1[n] = vet[i];
            n++;
        }
      }
    for (i = 0; i <n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", vet1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```